# how much important html5 validate for Microdata and how can I fix them?

Tags: html, validation, microdata

I checked my webpage on a html5 validator and I got 3 types of errors:

```
Error1: Attribute name not allowed on element link at this point.
From line 19, column 5; to line 19, column 56
!" />↩    <link name="twitter:url" href="http://localhost/" />↩

Error2: Element link is missing one or more of the following attributes: itemprop, property, rel.
From line 19, column 5; to line 19, column 56
!" />↩    <link name="twitter:url" href="http://localhost/" />


Error3: Element meta not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 1506, column 19; to line 1506, column 72
          <meta itemprop="itemListOrder" content="Descending" />↩
```

Comment: You'll need to post the html itself if you expect anyone to suggest a fix.

Comment: If you get validation errors then your bunch o' bytes is not HTML 5. It is only important to fix them if you want to make it HTML 5. If you're okay with just having a bunch o' bytes, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: sorry I forgot embed my code in stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The error report you posted is all the help you'll need. It quite clearly tells you what is wrong. And since this is info from the validator how could you expect more from us.

Comment: I think is clear question :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Error 1

Whatever that `name` attribute is that you stuck in the `link` tag isn't allowed. Perhaps one or more browsers implement non-standard extensions that make this do something (possibly each does a different thing). Other browsers will likely ignore it.

#### Error 2

Your `link` tag is doesn't have `itemprop`, `property`, or `rel` attributes. It seems fairly likely that most software will simply ignore the `link` tag altogether. Some software may use the link for something despite the fact that part of it is missing. If *I* write a browser, a `link` tag missing these attributes will cause your website to display a rickroll and nothing else.

#### Error 3

You stuck a `meta` tag under a `ul` one. It seems likely in this context that you may be targeting some browser that uses that for something (I have no clue what). Other browsers will likely either ignore it or use it to do something else you weren't intending.